# How to change value of a Cell BEFORE Change_Event Apply [Excel/VBA]

Tags: vba, excel

I need to change a value of a cell. For example, `Range("B1").value` is "Cake" and i do

```
Range("B1").value = "Bubblegum"
```

But, I have a `Worksheet_Change` event and when it starts, if I `MsgBox "Target.value"` it will be "Cake" and not "Bubblegum".

Here is my Event :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cellAdress As String
    cellAdress = Target.Column

    If cellAdress = 5 Then
        If Target.Value = "X" Then
            Range("F" & Target.Row).Value = "0,0€"
        ElseIf Target.Value = "O" Then
            If Range("A" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
                Range("F" & Target.Row).Value = Worksheets("Astreinte").Range("B10").Value
            Else
                Range("F" & Target.Row).Value = Worksheets("Astreinte").Range("B11").Value
            End If
        Else
            Range("F" & Target.Row).Value = "Valeur Incorrecte"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

And Here is my code

```
For Each myDate In DateMonthCorrespondante 
    Range("E" & (2 + Day(myDate))).Value = "O" 
Next
```

How can I change that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: please include the entire code, this is to little to help you right now.

Comment: There is something wrong with what you said. The `Worksheet_Change` events only triggers after you change a Value. You are saying that the value was Cake, you changed to Bubblegum and yet the `Worksheet_Change` returned Cake? I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: It was because i had a problem on my line 

     Range("E" & (2 + Day(myDate))).Value = "O" 

I protected my sheet before and... It didn't change the value of my Range. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the SelectionChange and Change events in tandem, viz

```
Dim v

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

MsgBox v

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

v = Target.Value

End Sub
```

All this goes in the sheet module. Then you can add conditions to restrict the situations in which you want the box to appear and so on.

Comment: I tried it but the selectionChange will take the value before it change. And i want it after. (Despite this, thank for your answer)

Comment: the "after" value is available as "Target" in the Change event ... whereas SelectionChange event is used to temporarily store the "before" value in "v" to have it at hand when the cell is changed

Comment: Okay ! Thank you for that :) !

Comment: Ah, looks like I misread your problem. Does @Moacir's solution solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the events before and re-enable after.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("B1").value = "Bubblegum" 
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, with your help i finally solved my problem.

I had an error in the line

```
Range("E" & (2 + Day(myDate))).Value = "O"
```

And because of the event, it didn't say it to me.